# Why cant java be used over C++ for all programming purposes

Tags: java, c++

It is said that Java overcomes all disadvantages of C++

> **Disadvantages of C++:**
>
> - Does not provide very strong type-checking. c++ code is  easily
>     prone to errors related to data types,
>     their  conversions, for example, while
>     passing arguments to  functions.
> - Does not provide efficient means for garbage collection,  as already
>     mentioned.
> - No built in support for threads.
> - Gets complex when u want to develop a graphics rich  application in c++
> - portability of code on various platforms, etc

Then why is there a need for C++ language ??  Why cant we just use Java for all programming purposes??

Comment: Why would you think Java is preferred over C++?

Comment: I prefer C# and C++ over Java OMG!!

Comment: "Right tool for the job."  Generalizing something like this is a sign of either bigotry or naïveté.

Comment: What if there's only one right tool for any job?

Comment: Depends on the job, I got a GUI working faster in Java than C++, however, I would not use Java on an embedded system.

Comment: Some people prefer Java, some of those prefer it because Java does less, rather than more than C++.  IMHO Java has many of the best features of C++ without many of its draw backs.  In summary, don't assume more is better.  There are more jobs in Java than C++ or C#, but this doesn't imply it is preferred.

Comment: Requesting to reopen this post as to discuss more on the topic, with the disadvantages of C++ and the advantages of java over c++ (as stated in the link provided by Rawheiser) and still the requirement of languages like C and C++ (don't know about C#)

Comment: Requesting to reopen as The subject has not been sufficiently discussed

Comment: i edited the above post so that the topic could be discussed and elaborated widely . please reopen the post

Comment: Yes, C++ has disadvantages. But so does Java. Just because Java was designed to avoid a few specific perceived flaws in C++, doesn't mean Java is better at *everything*. I'd say Java probably has *more* problems than c++

Answer (score 4):

Simple answers: Because memory management is hard, and the java standard library is pretty good.

Comment: True for C++, but not C#.  C# memory management is similar to Java, and .NET Framework is pretty good also.  I'm not (necessarily) saying that C# is preferred over Java, just that these reasons are valid for C++, but not C#.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a better question for Wikipedia to answer than here.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_C%2B%2B